# Merge two columns data into one column in another first table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want a query, in my case table1 and table 2 have different structure but id is the common field all i want is find the way to display the data from table1 and table2. on ===> id table1 = id table2 into table1

For example dbo.Personal_details having Emp_ID and dbo.Employees having the same column Emp_ID. I want to merge the Emp_ID values into dbo.Personla_details.

```
Personal_details:                  Employees:

Emp_id                             Emp_ID
1                                  1
2                                  2
3                                  3
4                                  4
5                                  5
6                                  6
7                                  7
8                                  8
                                   9 
                                   .
                                   .
                                   upto 550 records in this table
```

So, i want merge the Emp_ID of Employees into Emp_ID of Personal_Details.
How i merge the details.

Please Help me,

Thanks in advance,

Naresh.

Comment: Please post your table structures.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am editing the table structure

Comment: Naresh, are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will Help You....

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition>
[WHEN MATCHED 
THEN <merge_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]
THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN <merge_ matched> ];
```